# Drop down action bar/menu in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a drop down action bar/menu below title bar..with the slide from top animation.
I have created a new activity with theme > theme.dialog and added animation translate from top to bottom of screen but it drop from start of screen not from below the task bar where i have added a arrow for drop down menu.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not added any code here so its very difficult to predict whats the problem, but i can  give you an idea.

- Do one thing add a viewFlipper and align it below your title bar. and add your menu layout inside the flipper.
- set animation to flipper. and call startFlipping() and stopFlipping().

Thanks.

Comment: I just want to make something similar to when click the small button below title bar. a dash board opens similar to when we click file menu on windows explorer it opens a drop down list above the previous window..